# Using Read-Host to output information from a script

Tags: powershell, command, exchange-server

I am trying to run a script against exchange to bring back all of the mailboxes a certain user has access to. I want to be able to input the usersname using `read-host`. I currently have this:

```
$username = Read-Host("Please enter users username")

#Enable Exchange cmdlets
add-pssnapin *exchange* -erroraction SilentlyContinue

Get-MailBox | Get-MailboxPermission -User $username | FL > C:\MailboxPermissions.txt
```

However, when I run this via powershell, it asks for the username, looks like it is starting to run the script, then powershell just exits and there is not data outputted

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Are you running this just in powershell or the ISE, in other words do you run your script from the file, or are you working with it in the ISE Editor?

Comment: Well.. it's normal, you output everything to a file in the end `| FL > C:\MailboxPermissions.txt`. If you remove this part, you should see the results.

Comment: @Harvey I am wanting to run via powershell itself so that anyone who wants to run the script can do so.

Comment: @DarkLite1 and I am not getting any results whatsoever. It is closing the powershell window almost instantly after entering the username, when I know that it takes longer than this when I tested it using ISE

Comment: add another `read-host` after the `get-mailbox` just to stop the script and see the results, and update us with the error (if such)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the help

I finally figured it out and there were a couple of issues. It was to do with the result size. I added `-resultsize unlimited`:

```
$username = Read-Host("Please enter users username")

add-pssnapin *exchange* -erroraction SilentlyContinue

>Get-MailBox -resultsize unlimited | Get-MailboxPermission -User $username | FL > C:\MailboxPermissions.txt
```

It would also not work by running the .ps1 file as this was not run by admin, and it needs admin permissions to output to the location I want. Once I created a shortcut for it to run via the powershell.exe with admin credentials it is now working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are only out putting to the screen.

This means that when you run your script it will carry out the required action, print to screen and close the window immidiatly. In turn, this means you can't see the output.

As @DarkLite1 mentioned, you could output to a file.

Or, you could simply allow the console to wait before closing. This is done like this at the end of your code:

```
Write-Host "Press any key to continue ..."
$x = $host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey("NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown")
```

You may also need a `Write-Host` on the last action in your code snippet, I'm not entirely sure as I am not familiar with how `Get-Mailbox` works, but try it without first.

To summarize, You must keep the window open or print the results to file to actually see anything. The code you have currently will complete so fast you will never see any output.

Comment: It is being outputted to 'FL > C:\MailboxPermissions.txt', however, when I run it via powershell, rather than ISE it does not return anything

Comment: Put the Press any key in to see if it is printing anything unexcpected to the screen. Also, Check the suer you are running the powershell script has the privilages. and most of all. When you run your script dont forget to use an execution policy bypass `powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File "C:\PathToFile"`